# data attributes not being added to created element

Tags: javascript, video.js

I have created a new div element which I would like to add some data-attributes to so I have set up the following code:

```
vjs.LikeButton = vjs.Button.extend({
  /** @constructor */
  init: function(player, options){
    vjs.Button.call(this, player, options);
  }
});

vjs.LikeButton.prototype.createEl = function(){
    return vjs.Button.prototype.createEl.call(this, 'div', {
        'id': 'video-fb-like',
        'className': 'fb-like',
        'innerHTML': '',
        'data-send': "false",
        'data-layout': "box_count",
        'data-width': "55",
        'data-show-faces': "false",
        'data-colorscheme': "dark",
        'data-href': this.player().options().shareUrl
  });
};
```

The problem however is that the element gets the new class and id but the data-attributes aren't added. Can anyone advise on why this might be?

Comment: Did you try jQuery's `.data()` instead?

Comment: @Bigood This doesn't set attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the way video.js sets the properties:

```
el[propName] = properties[propName];
```

`data` attributes can't be set that way in browsers that support them. So you have to do it yourself, e.g. with

```
var button = vjs.Button.prototype.createEl.call(...
button.setAttribute('data-send', 'false');
```

Answer (score 0):

is this problem in IE browser?, as data-attributes is only supported in html5 , you may need to check your browser's compatibility.